# assign foreign keys from autoincrement primary keys in mysql

Tags: mysql

new to mysql, appreciate any help.

I have three tables: `organizations`, `locations`, and `shows`. I want to use the autoincrement-assigned primary keys from `organizations` and `locations` as foreign keys in `shows`. How do code mysql to pull the foreign keys for `shows` automatically when I enter values for this table? Or is it best practice to just manually assign when I enter values for each row in `shows` based on what the auto-incremented primary key automatically assigned?

Here is how I have created all three tables, and both `organizations` and `locations` have all the entries inserted already (and thus primary keys assigned via autoincrement):

**organizations**

```
CREATE TABLE organizations(
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    sex CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    start_year YEAR NOT NULL,
    end_year YEAR NOT NULL,
    notes LONGTEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
```

**locations**

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    address_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    address_lat FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
    address_long FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    notes LONGTEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
```

**shows**

```
CREATE TABLE shows (
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    organization_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
    location_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    cost DECIMAL (2,2),
    money_raised DECIMAL (6,2),
    charity VARCHAR(64),
    audience_size MEDIUMINT,
    band VARCHAR(64),
    blackface CHAR(1),
    drag CHAR(1),
    notes LONGTEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );


ALTER TABLE shows
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK1_shows
    FOREIGN KEY (organization_id) REFERENCES organizations(id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE shows
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK2_shows
    FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES organizations(id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Do the tables `organizations` and `locations` have another unique column value that you know about at the time you insert a record into `show`? For instance, `locations.name`? If not, how will you know which locations and organisations record you want to link to?

Comment: Yes, organizations_name and locations_name are in an Excel that corresponds to rows in table "shows."

Comment: Take a look at the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function. After you insert into a table with auto-increment, it returns the ID that was assigned. You can use this when you insert into the table with the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an insert statement which selects the *id* values from the other tables based on a name value, like this:

```
INSERT INTO shows (
    organization_id,
    location_id,
    date
) VALUES (
    (SELECT id FROM organizations WHERE name = 'my_org_name'),
    (SELECT id FROM locations WHERE name = 'my_loc_name'),
    '2016-05-01'
);
```

Of course, you would insert values for some other columns as well.

Comment: @user2337225, did this solve your issue? Could you give some feed-back?